# Why am I getting this error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, arraylist, typeerror

### I've created a list of characters named 'char' I thought this code would compare the user input but I am getting a TypeError

```
while True:
    sorubir = input("Enter a  character  name: ")
    for i in char:
        if sorubir.upper() == char[i]:
            print (sorubir)
        else:
            sorubir = input("Try again. Enter a  character name: ")
```

Comment: Can you provide the text of the error?

Comment: `i` is a character string. You cannot use it as an index in `char[i]` (That `i` must be an integer number or a slice.)

Comment: `i` is already the item in`char`. Do `if sorubir.upper() == i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for i in char` already refers to the actual character in the array. I believe you thought `i` to be its index. That would be written instead as `for i in range(0, len(char))`, where i would take an index value.

In your current code, simply changing `sorubir.upper() == char[i]` to `sorubir.upper() == i` should do the trick!

Comment: Hmm.. what does your `char` list look like? Is it all upper case?

Comment: Thank you! that solved my problem but now I've got another one. When I enter a valid value from the list, the code keeps executing the else statement as if it doesn't really compare it with the list. When I try the  for i in range (0,char) it says "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: upper case names and last names. Has it something to do with the space between them?

Comment: 1. The TypeError problem - oops, I've corrected that now (missing len()). 2. Could you show me an example, like `["BOB", "JENNY"]?

Comment: char = ['EMRE CAKIR', REYHAN BOZTAS', 'NILUFER SAGLAM']

Comment: If you're saying ["BOB SMITH", "JENNY MARIE"], and the user enters just "JENNY", then "JENNY" == "JENNY MARIE" will return false. You could try `if sorubir.upper() in i` instead, although this may create some false positives. eg. if you `sorubir = "BOB"`, and `i = "BOBBY LEE"`, this will evaluate to true.  ||| Alternatively, to be more rigorous, you could do `if sorubir.upper() == i.strip()[0]', to check if the user input matches the first name.

Comment: I tested the user input as, emre cakir (last name included) also with upper-case

Comment: Ah I see what is happening. Currently, when it finds a match, it will print that name out. However, for every mismatch, it will go to the else clause, and print the 'try again' line. You could instead do `while true: if sorubir == i: break; else: input("try again")`. You could then have your print statement after this loop.

Comment: It is hard to say this but I was defining the if statement as, if sorubir  == [i] instead of i. So it worked now thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Doing

> for i in char:

Unless it's a list of numbers will return the data stored in that index.

For example you could be doing

> char['foo']

That will return the type of error you were getting.

Instead try using

> for i in range(len(char)):

This will return an integer for each index of the list.